# improve select query performance and readablity

Tags: mysql, sql

> I have the following table `LOANACCOUNT`. I want to identify the account (`ID`, `CREATIONDATE`, `TYPE`) with most balance for each account type.

**Loan Account Table:**

```
    ID  CREATIONDATE        TYPE        BALANCE
    1   2019-10-10 16:44:42 FIXED       390.92951
    2   2019-10-10 16:44:42 REVOLVING   81.68381
    3   2019-10-10 16:44:42 DYNAMIC     818.80966
    4   2019-10-10 16:44:42 FIXED       166.83337
    5   2019-10-10 16:44:42 REVOLVING   888.93255
    6   2019-10-10 16:44:42 DYNAMIC     422.1623
    7   2019-10-10 16:44:42 FIXED       165
    8   2019-10-10 16:44:42 REVOLVING   122.37553
    9   2019-10-10 16:44:42 DYNAMIC     370.60668
    10  2019-10-10 16:44:42 FIXED       1101.10781
    11  2019-10-10 16:44:42 REVOLVING   387.35689
    12  2019-10-10 16:44:42 DYNAMIC     1.029
    13  2019-10-10 16:44:42 FIXED       420.85499
    14  2019-10-10 16:44:42 REVOLVING   0
    15  2019-10-10 16:44:42 DYNAMIC     233.53848
```

**Expected output:**

```
    ID  CREATIONDATE        TYPE
    10  2019-10-10 16:44:42 FIXED
    3   2019-10-10 16:44:42 DYNAMIC
    5   2019-10-10 16:44:42 REVOLVING
```

**My attempt:**

```
(select id, creationdate, type
 from LOANACCOUNT
 where type = 'FIXED'
 order by balance desc
 limit 1)
union
(select id, creationdate, type
 from LOANACCOUNT
 where type = 'DYNAMIC'
 order by balance desc
 limit 1)
union
(select id, creationdate, type
 from LOANACCOUNT
 where type = 'REVOLVING'
 order by balance desc
 limit 1)
```

My query is working because for the moment I have only this 3 types: FIXED, REVOLVING, DYNAMIC. But if I add a new row containing another type, my query must be edited in order to make it work.

Comment: use group by TYPE and you will get your result

Comment: You can get problems with your SQL where you select those first matching record where `balance` ties within a type..

Comment: imagine if you have `id|date` -> `1|2019-10-11`, `2|2019-10-11`  and you use `SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1` which of those records will be first and which one will be second? You can't predict that as this `ORDER BY` is non deterministic ("random") and the first matching record can change on every run..

Comment: To make it deterministic ("fixed") on every run you would atleast need to add one column with unique data in the `ORDER BY` like -> `ORDER BY date, id ASC/DESC` so you define what needs to happen with the ties.. Ideally that column needs to be a column with a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key that would make it 100% pure deterministic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sql statement

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  CREATIONDATE,
  la.TYPE
FROM 
  `loan account` la
  INNER JOIN
   (SELECT
     TYPE, MAX(BALANCE) BALANCE
    FROM 
     `loan account` 
    GROUP BY TYPE) la1
    on la.TYPE = la1.TYPE and
       la.BALANCE = la1.BALANCE
GROUP BY la.TYPE,CREATIONDATE,ID;
```

Gives you:

```
ID  CREATIONDATE            TYPE
3   2019-10-10T16:44:42Z    DYNAMIC
10  2019-10-10T16:44:42Z    FIXED
5   2019-10-10T16:44:42Z    REVOLVING
```

adapted  Thx to Raymond Nijland
example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecab9b/10

Comment: *"no i don't think so"* Well MySQL 5.6 in short is FUBAR... See MySQL 5.7 -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ZfiRxxvV7A21T6wLa8yiH/0 .. this gives the expected error -> *"SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.la.ID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"*

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MySQL | Recursive CTE (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/)

For Example:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT
`ID`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `TYPE` ORDER BY `BALANCE` DESC) AS RowNum
FROM LOANACCOUNT as t 
)
SELECT c.`ID`,`CREATIONDATE`,`TYPE` FROM LOANACCOUNT as t join cte as c on t.Id=c.Id WHERE c.RowNum=1
```

Comment: Thats SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax not MySQL, as those `[]` is totally invalid MySQL syntax and if your remove that it will work in MySQL 8 only..

Comment: Also MySQL/MySQL clients also does not like a starting `;` before the query, i believe thats a SQL Server (MSSQL) thing also..

Comment: I don't have much experience with `mysql` but in generally `CTE` starts with `;`  so I use that